# How can I convert a .cs file to a bookmarked Html document?

Tags: c#, html, syntax-highlighting, mono.cecil

I need to expose the inner details of a C# project in a web site.
In order to do this, I need to take a .cs file, have it converted to html, with some (could be basic) syntax highlighting and, ideally, anchors in the generated html, identifying methods, fields, properties, and so on.
I'm evaluating the custom parser route, but it would be a really difficult implementation, especially for a sub-project, so I wonder: what would you do?

I have .cs source files, the dll+pdb+xml output files, and I'm already using Mono Cecil to inspect the dll, so maybe there is a way to link methods in the output assembly to code lines in the source files. I can't find informations about Cecil.pdb, maybe there is something in there.

At last, the implementation of the syntax highlighter would be done either in C# (during the conversion to html) or in JavaScript, at runtime, but preferrably in C#, outputting static html files, with invisible  tags included.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds quite complicated. I would ask why you need it. You could use visual studio online and upload the files to the team foundation server using either TFS or GIT repository and then show the highlighted .cs files there. However, it is probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: Or if it is for documentation purposes, you could use some doc generator like sandcastle or doxygen, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641364/c-sharp-documentation-generator

Comment: It is, for documentation purposes. I'm creating a tool to replace SandCastle, and a nice feature, especially for open source projects, is a "link to source" in the documentation for each method. And this is why I would like it.

Comment: I see, is it wise to reinvent the wheel? Anyway, I would probably inspect the code of sandcastle and see how they do it. The other thing that comes to my mind is that you would mark the output html with css classes as you walk through the code using reflection and then simply design your css to your liking, but I do not think there is a tool for that.

Comment: In SandCastle, they do not: there is no "link to source code" in it. Doing some googling I came to the conlcusion that a combination of Mono.Cecil.Pdb and highlight.js is probably going to cover the requirements. Going to try that route.